# If $x^3 =7$, then $x$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, rationality-testing

Assuming there is a real number $x$ with $ x^3 =7$, prove that $x$ is irrational.

I started the proof by contradiction, and I got to the point that $7q^3 = p^3$, but I don't know what should I do after this.

Comment: I think you mean proof by _contradiction_, not induction.

Comment: How exactly did you do this by induction? Could you write out the steps?

Comment: Can you conclude something about prime factors of the integer $p$?

Comment: x^3 =7 then cube root(x^3 )= cube root of (7) then x= cube root(7).

Comment: suppose cube root(7) is rational then there exists integers p and g with q does not equal zero such that cube root(7)=p/q where p and q have no common factors qcd(p,q)=1. cube root(7)=p/q then (7^1/3 )^3 =(p/q)^3 then 7=p^3/q^3 then 7q^3=p^3

Comment: argue that $7\mid p^3\implies 7^2\mid q^3$, contradicting the assumption that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. Fill in the missing steps.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You can assume that $p, q$ are coprime. From $7q^3 = p^3$, you have $ p \mid 7q^3$. What can you deduce from this?

This proof will be very similar to the standard proof that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Comment: should I say p could be even or odd?

Comment: In the $\sqrt 2$ case we say that $p$ has to be even. Here that won't help too much. What else could you deduce from $p \mid 7q^3$?

Comment: it is 7q^3 =p what am I missing?

Comment: Can we have $p \mid q^3$?

Comment: yes, then p|q? then 7 divides both p and q?